# Equivalent of Java's toString() for Clojure functions

Tags: java, clojure, metadata, tostring

some Java code I'm using invokes `toString()` on my Clojure function objects, which return something like `#<ns$something something.something$something@7ce1eae7>>`- I want to return something else...presumably there's a way to include some metadata in the functions so their objects' `toString()` returns that instead ?

Comment: Why does it matter what the toString() is ?

Answer (score 15):

If you just want to make the REPL print-out of your objects more meaningful, you can implement a `defmethod print-method` for the class in question.

Here's a shortened version of some code I've written recently; this makes the REPL print-out of a Selenium-WebDriver WebDriver object more meaningful:

```
(defmethod print-method WebDriver
[o w]
(print-simple
 (str "#<" "Title: "    (.getTitle o) ", "
           "URL: "      (.getCurrentUrl o) " >")
  w))
```

This prints out like `#<Title: A Title, URL: http://example.com >`

Here, `WebDriver` represents a class; you can just as easily do this for built-in Clojure data structures by implementing `print-method` for the appropriate class (The Joy of Clojure features a `print-method` for `clojure.lang.PersistentQueue` which has no nice representation by default). The `o` above is the actual object you're dealing with and `w` is a writer (required by these kinds of print functions).

Comment: I can add, that you don't really need class for it, you can use (with-meta data {:type ::my-new-cool-type}) and (defmethod print-method ::my-new-cool-type [o w] ...)

Answer (score 11):

AFAIK, there's no simple way of doing this, though you can use reify or proxy to implement  clojure.lang.IFn  - which really just amounts to wrapping your function object in another object.

```
(def my-fn
  (let [f (fn [a] (println a))] 
     (reify clojure.lang.IFn
        (toString [this] "bla")
        (invoke [this a] (f a)))))


#'user/my-fn
user> my-fn
#<user$fn$reify__2903 bla>
user> (my-fn 2)
2
nil
user> (.toString my-fn)
"bla"
user> (str my-fn)
"bla"
```

Comment: nice one @joost-diepenmaat

Comment: You should also implement `applyTo` for seamless operation with spec.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything you can do about this: there's no way to ensure that your functions implement toString() differently without diving in and re-engineering the internals of Clojure.

However I think you can work around this problem quite easily - I'd suggest wrapping your functions within another class that you control (e.g. as defined through [**defrecord**](http://clojure.org/datatypes)) before passing to Java code - then you will be able to provide your own custom toString() method, as well as get all the other advantages of using a record.